# Why have some territorial annexations been rejected by the international community?

Tags: international-relations, border-dispute

The annexation of Kuwait by Iraq, the annexation of the Golan Heights by Israel, and the annexation of Crimea by Russia are examples of recent territorial annexations that have been rejected by the international community. **Under what circumstances has the international community historically accepted or rejected territorial annexations, and what were the reasons?**

Have the reasons remained consistent throughout history, or have they evolved after, say, the Peace of Westphalia and other international territorial agreements? How has "rejection" been handled (i.e. Iraq was invaded by the West but Israel and Russia were not), and has that been consistent? **What generally has to happen for an annexation to be accepted?** Has annexation against the will of the people living in the disputed territory ever been historically accepted, and what percentage of the population accepting the annexation is generally regarded as being enough? How can such will even be expressed or measured?

Comment: I think this belongs to politics.stackexchange. That said, a few thoughts: The rejection is based in the principle of not accepting change of frontiers through war/military force. The difference of response is based in just *realpolitik* (Israel is backed by the US, tackling a nuclear power is always dangerous, Iraq did not had any support and had captured an oil exporter country, which if allowed would gave it too much leverage).

Comment: @SJuan76: I actually do intend to ask a similar question on Politics.SE, but first I want to understand the **historical** aspect of annexation.

Comment: Your question needs to be a hell of a lot tighter and not ask "why" questions of states in general, since this requires a political theory in the form of political science.  There are at least three questions in your examples, and post-UN is way too broad for a single question, let alone post-Westphalia.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I see, thanks. Perhaps asking for specific examples of both accepted and unaccepted annexations would be better? I could then do the comparisons on my own and ask more focused questions. I just found the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation) on annexation which has some recent examples, but they are all biased and obviously the result of edit wars and nationalistic Wikipedia editing. The linked references are cherrypicked, i.e. no better than the article itself.

Comment: I see two problems. 1) there are too many discussion/politics questions - I suggest you concentrate on the bold question and edit down to the minimum. 2) the conditions change over time.  Assyria, Rome, Mesoamerica, historical China, all have different circumstances for accepting annexations. Can you narrow this to something that is less than a PhD scope?

Comment: Specific examples have, in the past, generated bad questions; it is difficult to tell when an example question has been answered. I would suggest that you focus on the criteria which cause **a specific** international community to accept territorial annexations.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Thank you. I am trying to understand why the international community rejects Israel's annexation of the Golan Heights. In contrast to Kuwait or Crimea, the Golan Heights were captured in **a defensive war**, i.e. the country that got the land was the attacked country. If the annexation is not accepted by the international community, then **there is no longer territorial risk for countries to start wars**. But of course I'm biased: I'm Israeli. I would like to **understand the historical precedent for such a rejection**. After that, I'll ask the proper questions on Politics.SE.

Comment: I object to the annexation of Quebec by Canada.

Comment: Before the post-WWI Society of Nations there was no such thing as an *international communauty* If the question is about contemporary annexations (or attempts of), ask on politics :)

Comment: @Bregalad That assertion would come as a great surprise to the participants of the Congress of Vienna (which adjudicated territorial annexations) or the Treaty of Westphalia, or the history of China and Korea, or MesoAmerica, or the kindgom of Meroe or the Assyrian Empire, or the Romans, or....

Comment: We've closed the question, but I'm confident that the answer would include as a factor a broad range of stakeholders who support or don't care about the annexation; that will never exist for Israel.  Israel's actions are better evaluated through politics than history.

Comment: I like this question, I want to answer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: That is why I ask about **the history of annexations** in general, not about the Golan Heights in particular. Would you disagree that it is important **to learn about history** in order to understand the present?

Comment: @dotancohen The purpose of your question concerning Golan is a matter of public international law. Of course, PIL questions require a review of history in the form of state practice. On the question of Golan, the history that is relevant is that of the period after 1945. The reason for the circumscription is that the international regime for territorial acquisition is new after 1945.  See any PIL textbook. Yes, there are exceptions to the prohibition against territorial annexation [see eg India and Goa] but none of them apply to the Golan. Perhaps this is for the projected law stack.

Comment: @EverardO'Donnell: Thank you, you've given me much material to google for.

Comment: @dotancohen: Most PIL textbooks are OK on general principles, but superficial on the exact issue. Probably the most comprehensive discussion is by the editor of Akehurst's Introduction to Modern International Law, Peter Malanczuk, 'Das Golan-Gesetz im Lichte des Annexionsverbots und der occupatia bellica', ZaoRV 42(1982), and 'Jerusalem', EPIL [1990], and 'Israel, Status, Territory and Occupied Territories', EPIL [1995]. See also the so-called 'principle of effectiveness', which I assume the government of Israel regards as its bright hope in the long haul. Good luck.

Comment: @EverardO'Donnell: Thank you very, very much! That's certainly enough material to keep me occupied, much less the Golan!